# whisper-merge appears to replace rather than aggregate duplicate values

Tags: graphite, whisper

I'd like to use whisper-merge to merge two whisper databases using an aggregation method, but it appears that one piece of data replaces the other if there's any overlap of timestamps.

Obviously graphite itself can aggregate data, but does anyone know of a command-line utility to perform aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use whisper-fill.py instead of whisper-merge to add missing data.

After that, execute whisper-set-aggregation-method.py to set aggregation defined.

Ref: https://github.com/graphite-project/whisper

Comment: Thanks. I don't think whisper-fill aggregates data, I think it will just take missing data and ignore overlaps?